# ambiguous component values (ex. U01 U47 M47 etc.)

Tags: capacitor, pcb, resistors, circuit-analysis

i'm having a hard time understanding components value when it's given in the following formate

U01
U47
M47
sometimes it's even worse like 4N7

i know that U for micro, M for mega, N for nano but i just can't seem to find a straight forward way to calculate it plus i've found conflicting answers so i thought it would be better to ask and know it correctly once and for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capitalization is important.

- U01 could mean 10 n and so could u01 as well as 0u01
- U47 = u47 = 0u47 = 470 n
- M47 probably means 470 k but m47 could mean 470 u because m = milli and M = mega

Basically the "alpha" character replaces the decimal point such that 10k1 = 10.1 k

This might help: -

[image]

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that for some very old equipment, we used μμF rather than pF.